# Erro Case e Group by - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, sqldeveloper

Olá, estou tentando agrupar os resultados de uma query com case da seguinte forma:

```
select 
    case
      when sal BETWEEN 0 and 100000 then 1
      when sal BETWEEN 100001 and 200000 then 2
      when sal BETWEEN 200001 and 300000 then 3
      when sal BETWEEN 300001 and 400000 then 4
    else 5 END AS "ESCALAO",
    count(*) AS "QTD"
FROM EMP
GROUP BY ESCALAO
ORDER BY QTD DESC;
```

Porém sem sucesso. A mensagem de erro que diz:

> ORA-00904: "ESCALAO": identificador inválido
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Erro na linha: 10 Coluna: 10

O que há de errado na query?

Comment: Nessa query está a linha 17 ?

Comment: Desculpe @Zoom , linha 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode usar o nome de uma coluna apelidada com **as** no Group By. Tente isso:

```
select ESCALAO,COUNT(*) AS QTD
from
(
    select 
        case
          when sal BETWEEN 0 and 100000 then 1
          when sal BETWEEN 100001 and 200000 then 2
          when sal BETWEEN 200001 and 300000 then 3
          when sal BETWEEN 300001 and 400000 then 4
          else 5 END AS 'ESCALAO'
    FROM EMP
)
GROUP BY ESCALAO
ORDER BY QTD DESC;
```

Comment: a única coisa que mudei foi colocar o apelido de ESCALAO com aspas assim: "ESCALAO". Muito obrigado pela ajuda!