# Oracle PL/SQL problema com AS

Tags: oracle

Boa tarde, estou com uma duvida em relação ao uso do AS em plsql numa database oracle

segue o codigo:

```
SELECT CC.NOME, SUM(1) AS QTD_CEL, SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS LIKE 'INATIVO' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS QTD_INATIVO , MIN(C.NEW_COL) AS DATA
FROM TB_CLIENTE CC, TB_CONTRATO C 
WHERE C.ID_CLIENTE=CC.ID_CLIENTE
AND QTD_CEL > 1
AND CC.SEGMENTO='EMPRESARIAL'
AND (C.ID_PRODUTO = 304
OR C.ID_PRODUTO = 305)
GROUP BY CC.NOME
```

e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
ORA-00904: "QTD_CEL": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 42 Coluna: 5
```

Aparentemente ele nao identifica o ALIAS como identificador, alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: AND QTD_CEL > 1 troque por um "having"     https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-having/

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Erro Case e Group by - Oracle SQL Developer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102441/erro-case-e-group-by-oracle-sql-developer)

Answer (score 1):

```
--creio que RESOLVA

SELECT CC.NOME, 
       SUM(1) AS QTD_CEL, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS LIKE 'INATIVO' THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL END) AS QTD_INATIVO , 
MIN(C.NEW_COL) AS DATA
FROM TB_CLIENTE CC, TB_CONTRATO C 
WHERE C.ID_CLIENTE=CC.ID_CLIENTE
AND CC.SEGMENTO='EMPRESARIAL'
AND (C.ID_PRODUTO = 304
OR C.ID_PRODUTO = 305)
GROUP BY CC.NOME,C.STATUS/*citado no case*/
HAVING SUM(1) > 1
```